# vb 2010 OpenFileDialog show specified file

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, openfiledialog

I will try to make this clear,
i have an application that opens the file location of a running process, however when the process is located in a large folder like system32 it just opens at the first item,

What i really want is for the specified .exe to be highlighted or in focus within the dialog window,
is there a way to filter or use the built in search box in the window programaticaly??

Many thanks

Comment: have you tried setting the Selected File of the open file dialog to match the file you want selected ?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `FileName` property to the file you want before showing the dialog.

Comment: i think i have but it was a while ago, ill give that a go now

Comment: ok tried that, remember now why it didnt work, i dont want to actualy open the file just Point the user at it, the FileName property would let you open it at a click if i wanted to do that, Thanks anyway, Perhaps there if a better method to do what i want i just dont know what it is